# HUD housing recertification removing someone from lease

Tags: united-states, housing

B"H

Hi

I'm trying to move out of HUD housing, and the re-certification has passed and my father has signed the documents without my signature re-certifying, which is what I want because I want to move out, but the manager said that I have to provide proof of residence at a new address in order to be removed from the lease, even after the recertification, but said she "wasn't sure", is this true?

If so, what if someone is homeless etc.? Will they be forcibly kept on the lease?